# how do I use a document using debug folder (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to show a document (called zzz.txt so it appears at the bottom) in a text box, and I have put it in the debug folder (TextViewerthingy > obj > Debug) and have used `CurDir() & "\zzz.txt"` for the location, which apparently is not correct. I have used this correctly with other projects

`Dim filename As String = CurDir() & "\zzz.txt"
Dim ObjReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)`
gives me an error saying the file is not there. This is the location, what is it that I'm doing wrong in this case?
C:\Users\Notshowingmyname\source\repos\TextViewerthingy\TextViewerthingy\bin\Debug

Comment: 1) You said you put the file in "obj\Debug" _(Wrong dir!)_ but looks like you're trying to find it in "bin\Debug" _(Right)_. 2) Always use [`Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to combine path parts. 3) `CurDir()` isn't really necessary. You can just use the filename ("zzz.txt") as long as it's in the same folder as your executable. 4) You shouldn't really put files in the Debug folder manually. Instead, include it in the project and set its `Copy Local` property to true, _or better use it as an embedded resource (google that)_.

Comment: Don't put anything directly into the Debug folder. Add the file to your project in the Solution Explorer, set the `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to output directory` to `True`. When you build, the file will be copied automatically to the appropriate folder.  You should then create the file path like this: `Dim filename As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "zzz.txt")`.

Comment: Correction: set `Copy to output directory` to `Copy if newer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
    Imports System.IO

    Dim filename as string = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\zzz.txt"
```

Or second alternative :

```
   filename = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory + "\zzz.txt"
```

Make sure file name and extensions are correct.